# Export different variables based on different class name in sass

Tags: webpack, sass

l want to share some variables between js and sass. l know that `:export` directive can do that. But is there a way to export different variables according to the judgment condition.

e.g

```
@if (className a) :export a;
@else if(className b) :export b;
```

l am new to Sass, l wanna to know is it possible? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I think that you cannot do that.